# Merge files line after line

Tags: shell, merge

I need your help with this query.

File-1:

```
What is your name?
whats your profession?
whats your interest?
Whats your favorite destination?
```

File-2:

```
My name is Combo
Executive
video games
stackoverflow forum
```

Need output as below:

```
What is your name?
My name is Combo
whats your profession?
Executive
whats your interest?
video games
Whats your favorite destination?
stackoverflow forum
```

I can simply use the below script, but my original file is around a thousand lines. A huge task to add echo before every questions.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?"
Combo
echo "whats your profession?"
Executive
```

Currently I have two notepads, one with echo and another with an answer for that. If there is a way to merge both file one by one, it will resolve my issue.

Comment: what is the type of file? how are the values separated? what is your OS? what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`paste`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) can do this for you:

```bash
paste -d '\n' file1.txt file2.txt
```